# Angular after adding @angular-architects/module-federation npm Project give runtime error

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I have added @angular-architects/module-federation NPM in existing project Angular version 16.
it project build successfully with ng serve but it throw an error on browser console

1. Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption
2. Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
   [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ0Xi.png)

to add module-federation i use below command
ng add @angular-architects/module-federation@16.0.4 --project Application --type remote --port 4230

I try with new project it working as expected.